# Able to edit custom post, but unable to create new custom post when within submenu. What capability is missing?

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu, capabilities, add-menu-page

I'm encountering funny behaviour with a custom post of mine that I'm working with in a plugin of mine. Here are the arguments of the custom post:

```
array(
    'label' => [omitted],
    'labels' => [omitted],
    'public' => false,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'menu_position' => 21,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-editor-help',
    'supports' => array('title','editor','comments'),
    'capability_type' => array('custom-post','custom-posts'),
    'show_in_rest' => false,
    'show_in_menu' => 'my-plugin' // Able to create posts with restricted user role if I remove this line.
)
```

Note that this custom post type is put inside of a menu, which requires a capability of `edit_custom-posts` to be able to access.

```
add_menu_page('My Plugin Module', 'My Plugin Module', 'edit_custom-posts', 'my-plugin','','dashicons-admin-network',21);
```

As I want to allow only site Administrators, as well as a custom user role (let's call them Plugin Admins), to be able to manage these custom post types completely. To this end, I've added the following capabilities to them:

```
$cap['edit_custom-post'] = true;
$cap['read_custom-post'] = true;
$cap['delete_custom-post'] = true;
$cap['edit_custom-posts'] = true;
$cap['edit_others_custom-posts'] = true;
$cap['publish_custom-posts'] = true;
$cap['read_private_custom-posts'] = true;
$cap['edit_published_custom-posts'] = true;
$cap['delete_published_custom-posts'] = true;
```

Everything works the way I want it to: Administrators and Plugin Admins have no problem accessing, editing and creating new custom posts, *if* I do not put the custom post under the `my-plugin` menu. When I do, Administrators still can create new custom posts, but Plugin Admins can do everything ***except*** create new custom posts. Instead, they will get a **Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page** error.

Anyone have any insight into why this is happening? What permission does the Administrator have that the Plugin Admins do not?

Comment: to compare permissions between roles, you can debug with https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an answer to this question with User Roles Editor, but I have worked around this problem by showing different admin panels for different users. When Plugin Admin logs in, the custom post type is not put under a menu, so they can create new custom posts. When the Administrator logs in, the custom post type will be put under a menu.